# Plot with 2y axis in log scale with ggplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make a plot with ggplot with 2 y axis and to implant a log scale within the 2 y axis.
I tried to add a second y axis with this

```
scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~ ./b, name = "Y2"))
```

and to add a log scale with this

```
scale_y_continuous(trans='log10')
```

but it deletes the second y axis and keeps just the first y axis with the log scale!

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. It’s easier to help if you make your question reproducible: include a minimal dataset in the form of an object for example if a data frame as df <- data.frame(…) where … is your variables and values or use dput(head(df)). Include the code you have tried and set out your expected answer. These links should be of help: [mre] and [ask]

Comment: You can only have one scale per aes, i.e. try `scale_y_continuous(trans='log10', sec.axis = sec_axis(~ ./b, name = "Y2"))`. Otherwise the second scale_y.. overwrites the first one.